# How to stub in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can't figure out why stub can't create in this source.
I'm trying to test the logic inside if statement.
`if user.nil? || company.nil?`
is the condition. For that purpose, I made spec definition as below.

```
  def introduce
    accountant_request = AccountantRequest.with_introduce_request_status(:requested).find(params[:id])

    company = Company.find_by(id: accountant_request.company_id)
    user    = User.find_by(id: company.try(:primary_user_id))
    if user.nil? || company.nil?
      redirect_to admin_accountant_requests_path, alert: 'There is no company or user' and return
    end
```

Here's the spec. My expectation is Company.find_by(...) returns nil.

```
  shared_examples 'post #introduce' do
    subject(:response) { post 'introduce', params_for_introduce }

    context 'error by user.nil? || company.nil?' do
      it 'fail' do
        allow_any_instance_of(Company).to receive(:find_by).and_return(nil)
        expect(response).to have_http_status 302
        expect(response).to redirect_to introduce_error_redirect_path2
      end
    end
```

Unfortunately, `company = Company.find_by(id: accountant_request.company_id)` returns existing record not nil. So I could not examine inside if statement.

What's wrong? And what should I do in this case?
Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

`allow_any_instance_of` should be used for an **instance** of the Company class, but here find_by is called on **the class itself**

Try this (before executing the test subject i.e the request) :

```
allow(Company).to receive(:find_by) { nil }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get it. I'll apply this modification next week and let you know the result.

Comment: @Samy_Kacimi I did what you've taught. But some error caused like '#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_companies_on_external_cid': INSERT INTO `companies` (`txn_number_format`, `name`, `name_kana`, `display_name`, `org_code`, `founding_year`,' What should I do?

Comment: I fixed by making stub for User. Thanks the advise. It's done